# Cordova: save login data in iOS keychain

Tags: cordova, authentication, keychain

I have the following login form in my Cordova app:

```
<input type="email" autocomplete="username">
<input type="password" autocomplete="current-password">
<button>Login</button>
```

The `autocomplete=""` attributes allow me to have email and password autofilled from existing logins in the keychain.

However, I cannot find a way to save the login, if the email address is not already in the keychain.

I have found Cordova-keychain plugins like the following. Unfortunately, these don't store the data as username-password combinations, so I guess that's useless here.
https://github.com/sjhoeksma/cordova-plugin-keychain-touch-id

Is what I am trying to accomplish impossible with Cordova?

Comment: Are your input fields in a form?

Comment: No, but I have already tried wrapping it in `<form></form>` or are there additional attributes needed?